# Check if num is between two double value - Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic

Why can't you do this if you try to find out whether an int is between two numbers:

```
if (16.5 < value < 17.5)
```

Instead of it, you'll have to do

```
if (value > 16.5 && value < 17.5)
```

which seems like a bit of overhead.

Comment: Its how dart2 language is built. Instead you can do 'if (16.5 < value && value < 17.5)'

Comment: [You can see from the API docs that < is a method on num witch returns a bool](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.5/dart-core/num/operator_less.html). If you break it down, the expression `16.5 < value < 17.5` is effectively `(16.5 < value) < 17.5`, and if we substitute `value = 20.0` then we get `(16.5 < 20.0) < 17.5` which evaluates to `true < 17.5`. Clearly it doesn't make sense to compare `true < 17.5`.

Comment: why are you not using `Extension Function` to reduce overhead ?

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan please let me know how can i use or create "Extension Function".

Comment: @RavinLaheri you can read about extension methods in [this link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

Comment: [Python allows chaining comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) (e.g. `a < x < b`), but Dart, like most other languages with syntax that descended from C, simply does not.  Comparison operators are not treated in any special way, so `a < x < b` will be parsed as a nested `(a < x) < b` comparison.

Comment: Okay Got it. @jamesdlin Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

### short answer

you can make own method like

```
between(value, 1, 10);
```

### long answer

you have to think about how the compilor works.

first. they have a some kind of parser that reads program language.

if you write 'if' conditional. a parsor read 'i' and 'f' character. then expect '(' sign.

```
if ( a > b )
```

check value, check sign, check value again, and check ')' sign.

The program then knows that this is a conditional statement. then make machine code like 01010101(idk. but we can't read something).

In this fomular. Finally comparing the values ​​is one by one(The compiler will work in the smallest unit possible).

Efficiency is very important at this stage. come back your code.

```
if (16.5 < value < 17.5)
```

and how about this?

```
if (16.5 < value > 17.5)
```

and how about?

```
if (16.5 > value < 17.5)
```

this is have many exception. But dart might be able to make this syntax. but they won't.

Because they too have to do the work of comparing one by one.

so you can make own method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can create short method and use it but i want to check that weather dart support this type of expression or not.

Comment: FYI, [Python allows chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) and does have well-defined behavior for `a < x > b` and `a > x < b`; it's mostly syntactic sugar for a compound expression of simpler comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

The "Clamp" function will return 17.4 if the value is greater than 17.4 and will return 16.6 if the value is less than 16.6. And the result will never be equal to "value". Therefore, the "Clamp" function is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
if (value.clamp(16.6, 17.4) == value) {
  // Do what you want to do
}
```

I think the `.clamp` function is to check if a number is less than the lower bound (16.6) or greater than the upper bound (17.4) or between the lower bound and the upper bound. If the number is less than the lower limit or greater than the upper limit, then display the lower or upper limit, otherwise display the number (I know by testing in DartPad)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it is not working.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer that what "clamp" function do.

Comment: @RavinLaheri I think the `.clamp` function is to check if a number is less than the lower bound (16.6) or greater than the upper bound (17.4) or between the lower bound and the upper bound. If the number is less than the lower limit or greater than the upper limit, then display the lower or upper limit, otherwise display the number (I know by testing in DartPad)

Comment: Great. I think it might help me I'll try this in my live project.

Comment: Good luck with your live project :)

Comment: @RavinLaheri does it help your live project?